# how to solve system of linear equations of XOR operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

how can i solve this set of equations ? to get values of $x,y,z,w$ ?
$$\begin{aligned} 1=x \oplus y \oplus z \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}1=x \oplus y \oplus w \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}0=x \oplus w \oplus z \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}1=w \oplus y \oplus z \end{aligned}$$

this is not a real example, the variables don't have to make sense, i just want to know the method.

Comment: As for every linear system. Recall that XOR is just addition modulo 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, you can just use any method you know for solving linear systems, I will use Gauss:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc|c||l} \hline
  x & y & z & w &\  & \\ \hline\hline
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \text{$+$ I}\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{$+$ I}\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \hline
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{III}\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \text{II}\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{$+$ III}\\ \hline
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \text{$+$ III}\\ \hline
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Now we can conclude $w = 0$ from line 4, which gives $z = 0$ from 3 and $y = 1$ from 2, and finally $x = 0$. So $(x,y,z,w) = (0,1,0,0)$ is the only solution.

Comment: can you explain please martini ? :)

Comment: @SalmaNafady Do you know Gauss' elemination method (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_elimination_method))?

Comment: Thanks for the answer martini :)
one more thing, what if the variables are matrices?
ex:
[1,0,0,1]=x⊕y⊕z
[0,1,0,1]=x⊕y⊕w
etc ?

Comment: Just consider each component seperately ...

Comment: im having a hard time understanding how gaussian works when using binary, especially with multiplication and division..

can you explain to me using your own words? :)

Answer (score 10):

I'll try it the 'artisanal way'.

These four rules should be enough :
$\begin{align}
&x\oplus 0=x\\
&x\oplus 1=\overline{x}\\
&x\oplus x=0\\
&x\oplus \overline{x}=1\\
\end{align}$

$\tag{1}1=x\oplus y\oplus z$
$\tag{2}1=x\oplus y\oplus w$
$\tag{3}0=x\oplus w\oplus z$
$\tag{4}1=w\oplus y\oplus z$

Applying $x\oplus$ on the three first equations and $w\oplus$ on the last gives :

$\tag{5}\overline{x}=y\oplus z$
$\tag{6}\overline{x}=y\oplus w$
$\tag{7}x= w\oplus z$
$\tag{8}\overline{w}=y\oplus z$

$(6)\oplus(7)\ $ gives $\ \tag{6'}1=y\oplus z$
so that from $(8)$ $w=0$
from $(7)$ and $(6)$ $\ x=z$ and $\ \overline{x}=y$
from $(5)$ $\ \overline{x}=1$ and the final conclusion :
$$(w,x,y,z)=(0,0,1,0)$$
as found (earlier) by martini...

Answer (score 7):

As others have noted, all the usual methods of solving systems of linear equations (such as [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)) in the [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) of [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) work just as well in the [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of integers modulo 2, also known as $GF(2)$.

In this field, addition corresponds to the [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR) operation, while multiplication corresponds to AND (as it does in the reals, if the operands are restricted to $0$ and $1$).  As both $0$ and $1$ are their own additive inverses in $GF(2)$ (since $0 \oplus 0 = 1 \oplus 1 = 0$), subtraction is *also* equivalent to XOR, while division is trivial (dividing by $1$ does nothing, dividing by $0$ is undefined).

---

So, let's try solving your example equations.  Since martini already did Gaussian elimination, let me do [Gauss–Jordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Jordan_elimination):

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
1x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 0w & = & 1 \\
1x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
1x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
\end{array}$$

The first coefficient of the first equation is already $1$, so we just subtract (XOR) that equation from the second and the third:

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
1x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 0w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
\end{array}$$

Now the second coefficient of the second equation is $0$, so we need to choose some later row that has a $1$ for that coefficient and swap those rows:

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
1x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 0w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
\end{array}$$

... and then subtract that row from all the others with a non-zero second coefficient:

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
1x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 0w & = & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Then we subtract the third row from those with a non-zero third coefficient:

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
1x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 0w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

... and finally the fourth row from those with a non-zero fourth coefficient:

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcr}
1x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 0w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 1y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 0w & = & 1 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 1z & \oplus & 0w & = & 0 \\
0x & \oplus & 0y & \oplus & 0z & \oplus & 1w & = & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

And now we can read  out the result: $x = 0$, $y = 1$, $z = 0$, $w = 0$.

Comment: Could you please explain, in the last step - how does 1 in the last column, second row, moves into the third row? I thought last column coefficient in fourth row is zero, so adding it should not change value.

Comment: @Alexander: Uh... magic? Definitely magic. Or I guess I just might have made a typo there...

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are fine, but you can use even more elementary (if somewhat *ad hoc*) methods, just as you might with an ordinary system of linear equations over $\Bbb R$. You have this system:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
1&=x\oplus y\oplus z\\
1&=x\oplus y\oplus w\\
0&=x\oplus w\oplus z\\
1&=w\oplus y\oplus z
\end{align*}\right.$$

Add the first two equations:

$$\begin{align*}
(x\oplus y\oplus z)\oplus(x\oplus y\oplus w)&=(z\oplus w)\oplus\Big((x\oplus y)\oplus(x\oplus y)\Big)\\
&=z\oplus w\oplus 0\\
&=z\oplus w\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $1\oplus 1=0$, so you get $z+w=0$. Substitue this into the last two equations to get $0=x\oplus 0=x$ and $1=y\oplus 0=y$. Now you know that $x=0$ and $y=1$ so $x\oplus y=1$. Substituting this into the first two equations, we find that $1=1\oplus z$ and $1=1\oplus w$. Add $1$ to both sides to get $0=z$ and $0=w$. The solution is therefore $x=0,y=1,z=0,w=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Fast Walsh–Hadamard Transform used to solve system of boolean linear equations with distorted right-hand sides. See implementation on https://fwht.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

as stated:

$(x \oplus y) \oplus z = 1 = (x \oplus y) \oplus w \Longrightarrow  z = w$

as stated:

$x \oplus ( y \oplus w ) = 1 = ( w \oplus y ) \oplus z \Longrightarrow x = z$  (AS $a \oplus b = b \oplus a$ )  SO $x = z = w$

substitute our 2nd conclusion:

$0 = x \oplus w \oplus z = x \oplus x \oplus z = 0 \oplus z = z \Longrightarrow x = z = w = 0$ (AS $a \oplus a = 0$)

substitute our 3rd conclusion:

$1 = x \oplus y \oplus w = 0 \oplus y \oplus 0 = 0 \oplus y = y \Longrightarrow y = 1$