# Find elements from xor relations

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations, propositional-calculus, combinatorial-game-theory, binary-operations

Alice and Bob are playing a game. Alice has a sequence of positive integers 
$$a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_N;$$ Bob should find the values of all elements of this sequence. Bob may ask Alice at most $N$ questions. In each question, Bob tells Alice $3$ distinct indices $i$, $j$, and $k$, and Alice responds with an integer 
$$a_i⊕a_j⊕a_k$$
($⊕$ denotes bitwise XOR).

How to approach this?
I thought about calculating xor queries for consecutive indices ($3$ indices at a time) and then proceed but that did not help me.

**Example**

a1^a2^a3=v1

a2^a3^a4=v2

…
and so on

Given N>=8

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3036582/find-unknowns-from-xor-equations).

Answer (score 1):

<s>This is a partial answer.</s>  See below for a complete winning strategy for Bob.  If $4$ divides $N$, then Bob can win the game.  I prove by showing that, Bob can find $4$ numbers by using only $4$ steps, thereby reducing $N$ to $N-4$.

The idea is as  follows.  Bob asks for the followings indices:

- $(i,j,k)=(N-1,N-2,N-3)$,
- $(i,j,k)=(N,N-2,N-3)$,
- $(i,j,k)=(N,N-1,N-3)$, and
- $(i,j,k)=(N,N-1,N-2)$.

Suppose that the answers by Alice are $b_N,b_{N-1},b_{N-2},b_{N-3}$, respectively.  Then, Bob knows the following numbers:
$$a_N=b_{N-1}\oplus b_{N-2}\oplus b_{N-3},$$
$$a_{N-1}=b_N\oplus b_{N-2}\oplus b_{N-3},$$
$$a_{N-2}=b_N\oplus b_{N-1}\oplus b_{N-3},$$
and
$$a_{N-3}=b_N\oplus b_{N-1}\oplus b_{N-3}.$$

---

Oh, snap!  The rest is easy.  Once Bob knows $a_N$, $a_{N-1}$, $\ldots$, $a_{n+1}$, then Bob can find $a_{n}$ in one step by asking for $(i,j,k)=(n+2,n+1,n)$.  Then, Alice returns some $b_{n}$, which Bob can deduce $a_{n}$ via
$$a_n=b_n\oplus a_{n+1}\oplus a_{n+2}.$$
Thus, Bob can win if and only if $N\geq 4$.

Comment: Here is a comment by @tech001 who doesn't have enough reputation to make a comment.  ***Additional condition***: for each index $i$, $i$ may appear in all questions in total at most $3$ times. What to do if number of positive integers are not a multiple of $4$, keeping in mind the above constraint because if i use this $a_n=b_n⊕a_{n+1}⊕a_{n+2}$ then the number of time a index is used becomes more than three?

Comment: @Snookie how would one approach if N was not a multiple of four??

Comment: @Batominovski can you help me out

Comment: @itachi101  I don't have the answer yet.  But your condition implies that each index $i$ must appear ***exactly three times***.  So the answer depends on whether we can construct a non-singular $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$ such that each row of $A$ contains exactly three $1$, and each column of $A$ contains exactly three $1$.

Comment: @Snookie  Thanks to your comment, I found an answer to this modified problem.

Comment: @itachi101  I think you are confused.  Snookie gave a complete answer (see the end of his answer).  But of course, if you are talking about the additional condition by tech001 (that requires that each index $i$ is asked by Bob at most three times), then I have provided an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to tech001's modification of the problem (see comments under [Snookie's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038458/find-elements-from-xor-relations/3038665#3038665)).  That is, for each index $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, Bob can ask Alice about it at most thrice.  Snookie's answer gives an indication how to reduce $N$ to $N-4$.  If $4$ divides $N$, then we are done.  Therefore, it suffices to prove that the task can be done for $N=5$, $N=6$, and $N=7$.

For $N=5$, Bob asks about the following triples $(i,j,k)$:

- $(1,2,3)$ for which Alice returns $b_1$,
- $(1,3,4)$ for which Alice returns $b_2$,
- $(1,4,5)$ for which Alice returns $b_3$,
- $(2,3,5)$ for which Alice returns $b_4$, and
- $(2,4,5)$ for which Alice returns $b_5$.

Then,
$$a_1=b_2\oplus b_4\oplus b_5\,,$$
$$a_2=b_2\oplus b_3\oplus b_4\,,$$
$$a_3=b_1\oplus b_3\oplus b_5\,,$$
$$a_4=b_1\oplus b_3\oplus b_4\,,$$
and
$$a_5=b_1\oplus b_2\oplus b_5\,.$$

For $N=6$, Bob asks about the following triples $(i,j,k)$:

- $(1,2,3)$ for which Alice returns $b_1$,
- $(1,4,5)$ for which Alice returns $b_2$,
- $(1,4,6)$ for which Alice returns $b_3$,
- $(2,3,4)$ for which Alice returns $b_4$,
- $(2,5,6)$ for which Alice returns $b_5$, and
- $(3,5,6)$ for which Alice returns $b_6$.

Then,
$$a_1=b_1\oplus b_5\oplus b_6\,,$$
$$a_2=b_2\oplus b_3\oplus b_5\,,$$
$$a_3=b_2\oplus b_3\oplus b_6\,,$$
$$a_4=b_4\oplus b_5\oplus b_6\,,$$
$$a_5=b_1\oplus b_2\oplus b_4\,,$$
and
$$a_6=b_1\oplus b_3\oplus b_4\,.$$

For $N=7$, Bob asks about the following triples $(i,j,k)$:

- $(1,3,5)$ for which Alice returns $b_1$,
- $(1,3,6)$ for which Alice returns $b_2$,
- $(1,4,6)$ for which Alice returns $b_3$,
- $(2,4,6)$ for which Alice returns $b_4$,
- $(2,4,7)$ for which Alice returns $b_5$,
- $(2,5,7)$ for which Alice returns $b_6$, and
- $(3,5,7)$ for which Alice returns $b_7$.

Then,
$$a_1=b_1\oplus b_2 \oplus b_3 \oplus b_5\oplus b_6\,,$$
$$a_2=b_1\oplus b_2 \oplus b_4 \oplus b_5\oplus b_6\,,$$
$$a_3=b_1\oplus b_2 \oplus b_4\oplus b_5\oplus b_7\,,$$
$$a_4=b_1\oplus b_3\oplus b_4\oplus b_5\oplus b_7\,,$$
$$a_5=b_1\oplus b_3\oplus b_4 \oplus b_6 \oplus b_7\,,$$
$$a_6=b_2\oplus b_3\oplus b_4 \oplus b_6 \oplus b_7\,,$$
and
$$a_7=b_2\oplus b_3\oplus b_5\oplus b_6\oplus b_7\,.$$
The case $N=7$ is extracted from [Federico](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/180428/federico)'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033987/finding-numbers-by-given-xor-values/3034013#3034013).

Comment: @tech001  Here is a solution to your modification of the problem.