# Eliminating the number of variables in an underdetermined system of Boolean equations

Tags: boolean-algebra

As an example, in an underdetermined system of linear equations, we can eliminate the number of variables by substituting them.

As an example:

a+b+c+d+e=5

a+2b+3c+4d+5e=13

a+5b+4c+2d+9e=22

With five variables and three equations, we can reduce the number of variables to two:

a+b+c=5-d-e

a+2b+3c=13-4d-5e

a+5b+4c=22-2d-9e

Solve a, b, and c and representing them using d and e; essentially substituting a, b, and c with formulas containing d and e.

Now, consider a set of Boolean equations, with five variables and three equations. Can we perform a similar method (representing/substituting three of the variables with the other two) to reduce the number of variables? I'm still very new to Boolean algebra, and I am not very familiar with them - so please correct me if I have made any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the types of equations, i.e. the operators being used.

For [XOR](https://www.electrical4u.com/exclusive-or-gate/) equations, [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is possible as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169921/how-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-of-xor-operation).

What happens, if the equations are restricted to disjunctions of variables?

Example:

$$a \lor b \lor c = 1$$
$$d \lor e \lor f = 0$$
$$a \lor f = 1$$

In this example, values for $d$, $e$ and $f$ must be $0$ due to the second equation. $a=1$ solves the other two equations, leaving $b$ and $c$ as *don't care* variables. This kind of inference or deduction is also called [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)).

Try to solve the following set of equations:

$$x\vee y\vee z=1$$
$$x\vee y\vee \neg z=1$$
$$x\vee \neg y\vee z=1$$
$$x\vee \neg y\vee \neg z=1$$
$$\neg x\vee y\vee z=1$$
$$\neg x\vee y\vee \neg z=1$$
$$\neg x\vee \neg y\vee z=1$$
$$\neg x\vee \neg y\vee \neg z=1$$

[Source](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/20118)

Unlike in sets of linear equations, one cannot combine arbitrary Boolean equations to eliminate variables.

One common practical way to solve a set of Boolean equations is to translate the equations into [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) clauses and feed these into a [SAT Solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT).