# How can I do Gaussian elimination of a $32 \times 32$ bit matrix?

Tags: matrices, cryptography, binary, gaussian-elimination, hash-function

I have been looking at how to reverse the sigma operation in the sha256 hash and in several places I have seen that you have to make a $32 \times 32$ bit matrix and then solve it with Gaussian elimination.

On this same page I have found this question that is quite well formulated and well answered but I cannot finally understand how it does the elimination. [How to solve a system of 32 XOR equations via Gaussian Elimination?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060086/how-to-solve-a-system-of-32-xor-equations-via-gaussian-elimination)

I have spent several days trying to understand and I have been seeing how to solve the elimination and I manage to understand it with a smaller matrix with its unknowns as in this other question [how to solve system of linear equations of XOR operation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169921/how-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-of-xor-operation)

In the first link, start with the following matrix.

```
0:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
1:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
2:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | 1
3:  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 1
4:  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0
5:  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 | 0
6:  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 | 0
7:  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
8:  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
9:  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
10: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
11: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
12: 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
13: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | 0
14: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0
15: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0
16: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 | 0
17: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 | 0
18: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
19: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
20: 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
21: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
22: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
23: 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
24: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
25: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
26: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
27: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
28: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
29: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
30: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | 1
31: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0
```

I understand that the bit part on the right `01110001101010000010010011100110`, is the output of the sigma operation.
But where does the bit `00000000000000100000000001000000` part with which it does the right rotates come from?

The first link is a part of the question owner's total question and if we follow the link it leaves,([Reverse SHA-256 sigma0 function within complexity of O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607696/reverse-sha-256-sigma0-function-within-complexity-of-on#comment117747179_66607696)) it takes us to stack overflow where the answer marked as correct contains a series of hexadecimal numbers called "sigma0 singleton inverses" that I would like know that they are ignored and create new doubts as if they are constant values, or if they are obtained from another operation... If so, I would like to know what operation it is

I mean this part : `sigma0_singleton_inverses = [0x185744e9, 0x30ae89d2, 0x615d13a4, 0xdaed63a1, 0x9cd03a8e, 0x08fdcc39, 0x11fb9872, 0x23f730e4, 0x5fb92521, 0xbf724a42, 0x57ee6948, 0xafdcd290, 0x76b358ec, 0xf531f531, 0xc36917ae, 0xb78f9679, 0x4615d13e, 0x947ce695, 0x19a4740f, 0x2b1facf7, 0x4e681d07, 0x84877ee7, 0x385344eb, 0x70a689d6, 0xf91a5745, 0xc36917af, 0xb78f967b, 0x4615d13a, 0x8c2ba274, 0x290afdcd, 0x4a42bf73, 0x94857ee6 ]`

What do these "sigma singleton inverse" values mean?

I don't know if I posted the question in the right place since it contains topics about cryptography, mathematics and programming and I didn't know where to post it. If I made a mistake putting it in this section, tell me so I can correct it and publish it in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is slightly confusing in that the bits are arranged in reverse order, least significant first, so that the right shift/rotate becomes left shift/rotate. Each row is the result of applying the $\sigma_0$ function to a $32$-bit word with a single bit set. For instance, the first row shows the result of applying it to the word with only the $0$-th bit set. The right rotate by $7$ produces a $1$ in the $25$-th bit, the right rotate by $18$ produces a $1$ in the $14$-th bit, and the right shift by $3$ shifts the $1$ bit beyond the end of the word and thus doesn’t contribute in this case. You can see how it first becomes relevant in row $3$, which is the result of applying $\sigma_0$ to a word with the $3$rd bit set, because here the right shift by $3$ shifts that bit into the $0$-th bit.

The “singleton inverses” are the rows of the inverse matrix; for instance, the $0$-th entry in that array, $185744\mathrm E9_{16}=00011000010101110100010011101001_2$, is the result of applying the inverse operation to a word with only the $0$-th bit set. So they’ve inverted the binary matrix and provided the rows of the inverse, so you can apply the inverse operation as shown in the code there, “adding” (i.e. XORing) up the contributions for the bits, adding in the value in the array whenever the corresponding bit is set in the word to be inverted.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to answer this question and to review and understand the others in the links.
I understood perfectly the part of the singleton inverses and in the part of the matrix, thanks to you now I have a clearer vision of what is going on in it and I can understand the sudden appearance of the 1 in the third row, but what does it mean that the first row shows the result with the 0 set?

Comment: If you don't mind, with an example I think it would help me. For example what would be the matrix and the input if I have the following 32 bits as output? 1111000111111111111111111100011110000000
To add, I found this page that has a very similar matrix, is it a coincidence? http://www.chrisjones.id.au/Invert/index.html

Comment: @jefreyitbhernandezrodriguez: I'm not sure whether I understand your first question, "what does it mean that the first row shows the result with the $0$ set?". If you mean the $0$ at the very end of the row labeled "$0$:", I thought you said in the question that you understand that this is the desired output for which we want to find the input – there's not more to it than that; it's just the $0$th bit of the output we want to reverse in this example. On your next question: the matrix doesn't depend on the output being reversed; it's entirely determined by the hash function.

Comment: @jefreyitbhernandezrodriguez: I don't really feel like carrying out the computation for you; it's the same for every given output. If you want to do the computation for lots of outputs, it may make sense to actually invert the matrix so you just have to multiply the outputs with the inverse. If you only need it for a couple of outputs, it's probably more efficient to solve the system using Gaussian elimination. If there's a specific part of that you don't understand, feel free to ask again. About that other page: Why should it be a coincidence? They're doing exactly the same sort of thing.

Comment: No problem, it was just if you could. Thanks to you I have been able to see the problem even more clearly. If I have any more questions, I will create another question.

Comment: I just posted a representation of the inverse matrix.

Comment: Have you seen this question about the very same matrix and its answer I have just noticed : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060086/305862 ?

Comment: @JeanMarie That's the post I put in my question to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for having not made the connection.

Answer (score 2):

I would like just to illustrate the excellent answer by Joriki by displaying the inverse matrix, illustrating two facts :

1. that indeed the binary (or hexadecimal) codes of the rows have to be read in the backward direction.
2. that constracting with the initial matrix, its inverse (on the right) has a weird structure... The only special feature one can recognize on it is its symmetry with respect to the second diagonal shared with ( = inherited from) the initial matrix.

[image]

Fig. 1 : The initial matrix and its inverse.

Check for example that the second row of the inverse is (when read backwards)

$(0011)(0000)(1010)(1110)(1000)(1001)(1101)(0010)$

$ \ \ \ \ \ 3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ e \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  8  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   9  \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  d  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   2$

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, I appreciate the time in making an illustration, that was just what I was asking for earlier to have a visual image. This certainly makes my doubt and what I am facing even clearer.